# Discord bot that kicks everyone only kicks people without roles

Tags: python, bots, discord

Hello I was making a discord bot that kicks everyone in group but the only problem is that it only kicks members without any role. If someone could give me a boost because I'm learning discord py slowly.

Code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def free(ctx):
    guild=ctx.message.guild
    for member in tuple(guild.members):
        try:
            await member.kick()
        except:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `try` `except`. It displays you the error why it cannot kick a Discord member. My guess is that the member the bot tried to kick is higher in hierarchy and these people the bot cannot kick.

https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/214836687-Role-Management-101

> Additional to the role sorting hierarchy, there's a special exception
>   placed on banning, kicking, and nicknaming members: **Even if users have
>   ban/kick/nickname permissions, they cannot ban / kick / change
>   nicknames of anyone with the same role or a role higher than theirs.**

Comment: I was testing. I invited 5 bots and removed all of theirs permissions and give them very bad role and my bot still could't kick anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your bot's role is higher than all of them.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def free(ctx):
        members = ctx.guild.members
        for member in members:
            await member.kick()
```

You do not need the try except and tuple.